# Emacs could not find the the directory for eieio-1.4

Tags: macos, r, emacs, ess

I am an absolute Emacs newbie, but I am determined to learn it and learn from it. I am using Mac OSX 10.8.3 and Emacs Version 24.3 [from here](http://emacsformacosx.com/). I did the Emacs tutorial and sat Emacs up with R using [Kieran Healy's Emacs Starter Kit for the Social Sciences](http://kieranhealy.org/resources/emacs-starter-kit.html).

Everything worked great until suddenly I got a strange error message, I messed around (sorry I did not document or recall what it said), but I somehow installed what it asked for. Now I am stuck for real at a new error, namely that Emacs *could not find the directory for eieio-1.4* (see screenshot below).

Is there an easy fix for this? Should I try reinstalling and if so what is the smartest way to make a clean installation of Emacs?

[image: Emacs could not find the the directory for eieio-1.4]

Comment: Your emacs is probably not correctly installed. There is another emacs distro for mac [here](http://vgoulet.act.ulaval.ca/en/emacs/). That includes auctex and ESS and is known to work well. You can try to instal that one and then install the starter kit. If that doesn't work you should probably report this issue on github page of the starter kit.

Comment: The starter kit you're using (mine) doesn't hard-code any paths to specific eieio versions ... Maybe you installed additional packages from somewhere? It'd be helpful if you could give more information about where the startup process fails.

Comment: Thank you for responding to my outcry. @Kieran, I could have installed additional packages, but I don't think that's the case. The _startup process_ doesn't really fail. I start Emacs by typing `Emacs` in iTerm.app and when I does that it start up Emacs and opens the last session I was editing, but splits the screen with the message in the screenshot above in the bottom window (btw, thanks for making the kit)

Comment: I've been trying to reproduce this but haven't been able to. On my test machine, if I install Emacs from `http://emacsformacosx.com` and freshly clone the starter kit, it loads, installs remote packages, and launches as expected. The only error I encountered on one of a few  tries was Emacs failing to fetch packages, but `M-x list-packages` and relaunching fixed that. You might try upgrading your packages—`M-x list-packages` then `U` to mark upgradeable ones and `x` to install them.

Comment: @Kieran, I really appreciate your efforts! I tried running `M-x list-packages` and it did go through some steps and contacted a server, but stopped with this error message, `Internal error: could not find directory for eieio-1.4` I think the smartest thing (with my level of Emacs knowledge) is to reinstall it all). Thanks!

Comment: I also tried `M-x eieio-version` and to my surprise it wrote 1.4 in the mini buffer, so there is some information in my Emacs installation about a _eieio_ version.

Comment: @Kieran, I ended up reinstalling emacs and your starter kit. Tanks for responding to my post!